# Error Exception Caused by java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, exception

I have a problem, my code shows me:

```
Exception caused by java.io.EOFException
```

What does this mistake mean? I would like to import an object
and if one enters the wrong name that one must repeat it and does not
indicate this error

**Code**

```
public List<order> importorders(String dataName)
List<order> orders;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dataName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can Not find " + dataName + "' not read!", e);
    }
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
    try {
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can Not Create ObjectInputStream", e);
    }
```

Comment: Your `importorders(String datName)` here the string parameter is `datName` but in here `FileInputStream(dataName)` it is `dataName` ... I guess you need some debugging first.

Comment: add code of both serialization and deserialization